# Failed to access a Color CCD camera interfaced with EasyCap USB 2.0 (Audio-Video Adapter) in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have CCD camera with RCA connectors. Now I have to interface this CCD camera with my laptop so that i can use it as webcam. Hence i opted for Easycap USB 2.0 audio-video adapter (http://easycap.co.uk/) to get the video signal from camera RCA connector to USB so that i can plugin to my laptop. Once after installing Easycap driver, I was able to interface the camera with my laptop.

When I tried to access the same interfaced camera using openCV, it was not happening :(. But with the same piece of code , i was able to access inbuilt USB camera in my laptop. Please tell me, why im not able to read the CCD camera as device when interfaced using EasyCap. Where am'i going wrong !!!!!

The code which i used to access the CCD camera was ::

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
# include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

cvNamedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

IplImage *img1=NULL;

while( 1 ) 
{
img1 = cvQueryFrame(capture);

 cvShowImage("video", img1);

if( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
}
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "video" );
return 0;
}
```

Hope Im clear...Thanks in advance ..

Comment: I also tried changing the index value of the installed device as CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0) or CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1)... still no changes

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It seems that the EasyCap can't be treated as a common camera. [link]http://sourceforge.net/projects/syntekdriver/forums/forum/616182/topic/2803299/index/page/7 maybe helpful